# Insert html at cursor in a iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, editor, range

Here is what I found: http://jsfiddle.net/jwvha/211/

This example works very well across browsers (in IE6~IE10, Chrome, Firefox, etc).

I have modified it to work within an iFrame, here is my approximate code:

```
insertHtml : function(html){        
    iframe.contentWindow.focus()
    var sel, range;
    if (iframe.contentWindow.getSelection) {
        sel = iframe.contentWindow.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();

            var el = document.createElement("div");
            el.innerHTML = html;
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
            while (node = el.firstChild) {
                lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
            }
            range.insertNode(frag);

            if (lastNode) {
                range = range.cloneRange();
                range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                range.collapse(true);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    } else if (iframeDocument.selection && iframeDocument.selection.type != "Control") {
        // IE < 9
        iframeDocument.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
    }
}
```

This works very well in IE6 - IE8, but in IE9 and IE10 I'm receiving the following error:

> SCRIPT5022: WrongDocumentError

at this line: `range.insertNode(frag);`

I did not know why this happened, and how to resolve it, so I had to use my broken English to seek help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are creating the new Fragment against the current document, then trying to append it to the IFrame. Try creating your elements like this:

```
var el = iframe.contentDocument.createElement("div");
el.innerHTML = html;
var frag = iframe.contentDocument.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
```